# how do I post an class to WebApi

Tags: class, post, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code on my WebAPI ...

```
public class OrderDetail {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
} 

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultPostApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{passKey}"
);


[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage AddPost(string passKey, OrderDetail order)
{
// string PostedOrderDetailName = order.Name
}
```

I wonder how I send the OrderDetail class from my client to the servers WebAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Serialise the OrderDetail object to JSON
- Pass it to the ApiController in your ajax object